# Python - How to move menu buttons to left side in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button, menu, frame

I created a frame for the menu buttons in my main screen and put in the top and then i told it to grid the buttons all in the row=0 and column=0 and column=1 and column=2 but it grids them in the middle of the line. Here is the code and the result :

[image]

[image]

There is no other frame in that row and all the frames have at least columnspan=3 but it just grids them in the middle of the line. What do i have to do?

Comment: Don't post image of code, post the code as text.  How do you put the frame containing those menu buttons?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Most likely you're putting the buttons in a frame, and the frame is centered in the window. Without seeing more code it's impossible to say for certain.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where is placed your button, but you can try this:

```
View_Menu.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
```

> `sticky` may be the string concatenation of zero or more of N, E, S,
> W, NE, NW, SE, and SW, compass directions indicating the sides and
> corners of the cell to which widget sticks.